# convert list of integers to bytes/ascii string and back ? Fast?

Tags: python, string, list, pack, unpack

I'm trying to convert list of numbers to string and reverse.. here is what i got

```
def nums2ascii(nums,size=2):
    return b''.join([n.to_bytes(size,'big') for n in nums ])


def ascii2nums(ascii,size=2):
    return [int.from_bytes(ascii[i:i+size],'big') for i in range(0,len(ascii),size)]
```

first problem is that this is the slowest method

I read that the way to go is to use struct module to make it fast.  there are too many mnemonics, how do i do it simply 2,4,8. Do i read it correctly '>I', '>R', '>Q' ?
Can I just pass the list to pack/unpack directly instead of doing list-comprehension ?

My second question is how transparently to handle int8, int16,, int32,int64 ... do i stick with the largest one OR do I make a decision to stick with specific one across the app /in which case i have to put an assert !!

Comment: You might want to look at the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) module.

Comment: The second function body could become `[int.from_bytes(ascii[i:i+size], 'big') for i in range(0, len(ascii), size)]`, no need for the nested comprehension.

Comment: @Dennis .... duuh ;) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, assuming the system short "h" is two bytes (it usually is):

```py
import struct

def nums2bytes(nums):
    return struct.pack(f">{len(nums)}h", *nums)

def bytes2nums(b):
    return struct.unpack(f">{len(b)//2}h", b)
```

You could maybe build out functionality that says that 2 is "h", 4 is "i", etc. Note that capital letters denote unsigned integers, lowercases denote signed.

An alternative is to install numpy and use numpy arrays.